# Laravel - I can't input data to my database

Tags: php, laravel

so I want to create 2 stores in 1 controller. when I input I did return to the index page, but the data I submitted did not exist. then I saw my localhost, but the data that I entered was also not there. when I input there is no error message. so I don't know where my mistake is.

here's my view

**createincome.blade.php**

```
@extends('admin/admin')
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            {{ Form::open(['route'=>'financials.incomestore', 'files'=>true]) }}
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Tambah Keuangan</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        @if(!empty($errors->all()))
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            {{ Html::ul($errors->all())}}
                        </div>
                        @endif
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {{ Form::label('date', 'Tanggal') }}
                                    {{ Form::text('date', '', ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'date', 'name'=>'date', 'placeholder'=>'Masukkan Tanggal']) }}       
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {{ Form::label('description', 'Deskripsi') }}
                                    {{ Form::text('description', '', ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Masukkan Deskripsi Keuangan']) }}      
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {{ Form::label('income', 'Pemasukan') }}
                                    {{ Form::text('income', '', ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Masukkan Pemasukan']) }}        
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {{ Form::label('file', 'Laporan Keuangan') }}
                                    {{ Form::file('file', ['class'=>'form-control']) }}        
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <a href="{{ URL::to('admin/financials/index') }}" class="btn btn-outline-info">Kembali</a>
                        {{ Form::submit('Proses', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right']) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- </form> -->
            {{ Form::close() }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {            
    $('#date').datepicker({                      
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        autoclose: true,
        }); 
    });
    </script> 
@endsection
```

here's my controller

**FinancialController.php**

```
public function incomestore(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $rules =[
            'date'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
            'debit'=>'required',
            'file'=>'required|mimes:pdf'
        ];
 
        $pesan=[
            'date.required'=>'Judul Kegiatan Tidak Boleh Kosong',
            'description.required'=>'Tanggal Kegiatan Tidak Boleh Kosong',
            'debit.required'=>'Jenis Kegiatan Tidak Boleh Kosong',
            'file.required'=>'Laporan Tidak Boleh Kosong',
        ];
 
        $validator=Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules,$pesan);
 
        //jika data ada yang kosong
        if ($validator->fails()) {
 
            //refresh halaman
            return Redirect::to('admin/financials/index')
            ->withErrors($validator);
 
        }else{

            $file=$request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
             
            $financials=new Financials;
 
            $financials->date=Input::get('date');
            $financials->description=Input::get('description');
            $financials->debit=Input::get('debit');
            $financials->kredit=Input::get('kredit');
            $financials->file=$file;
            $financials->save();
 
            Session::flash('message','Data Berhasil Ditambah');
 
            return Redirect::to('admin/financials/index');
        }
    }
```

and here's my route

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/admin/financials/index', [App\Http\Controllers\FinancialsController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/admin/financials/createincome', [App\Http\Controllers\FinancialsController::class, 'createincome']);
Route::post('/incomestore/financials', [App\Http\Controllers\FinancialsController::class, 'incomestore'])->name('financials.incomestore');
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to build out an instance of Financials and then write it to the database using ->save(). Are you certain that that code is being executed? What happens if you change: 

$financials->file=$file;
            $financials->save();

to 

$financials->file=$file;
dd($financials);

Do you see the data you would expect to see?

Comment: check all data inside the request body `dd($request->all())`

Answer (score 0):

Check if the model `Financials` has the columns (*date* / *description* etc.) in `protected $fillable` array.

It's a common mistake to miss those, and difficult to debug as it silently ignores the columns.